# boundary states of higher-order topological insulators

Tags: topological-insulators, tight-binding

What are the standard computational methods used in obtaining the edge and corner states of higher-order topological insulators? From my understanding, the DFT code calculates the bulk properties of a system with periodic boundary conditions, which is then used to generate a tight-binding model.

If we consider a square lattice in two dimensions. I think that the way one computes edge modes is to construct a geometry that has four boundaries, so there is no periodicity in either the $x$ or the $y$ direction. One then computes the edge and corner states using the given geometry, by diagonalizing a finite-dimensional hopping Hamiltonian. Is this correct?

Comment: I gave my +1 a long time ago, but just wanted to check how things are going with this question. Did you figure out an answer? Are you still working on this?